Given a representation, trying to find a non degenerate representation without changing kernel
Let $A$ be a $C^{\ast}$-algebra and $\sigma : A\to\mathcal B(H)$ be a degenerate representation of $A$ such that $H_0 := \overline{\sigma(A)H}\neq H$, then letting $H_1 := H_0^\perp$ (so that $H = H_0\oplus H_1$), we can define a non-degenerate representation $\rho:A \to B(H_0) $ by restricting $\sigma$ to $H_0$. It is clear that $ker(\sigma) \subseteq ker(\rho) $

Is it true that $ker(\rho) \subseteq \ker(\sigma) $


The kernels are always equal. The "restriction" is happening in the codomain, not the domain. That is, you have
$$
\sigma(a)=\begin{bmatrix} \rho(a)\\0\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
So $\sigma(a)=0$ if and only if $\rho(a)=0$.
